# Specific characters in textbox

Tags: c#, character-encoding, textbox

I want to make textbox in C# just accept numbers, one decimal point and negative sign just at first of textbox and i try this code:

```
 var txt = (TextBox)sender;

        if(e.KeyChar == 46 && txt.Text.IndexOf('.')!=-1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        if(!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == 45 && (sender as TextBox).Text.Length > 0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

negative sign not vaild , can you help me ?

Comment: Which UI Framework (WinForms, WPF, Xamarin, ASP.NET)? Which event do you handle with your code? What problem do you have?

Comment: @KlausGütter is correct. Give us some other details on your problem. Because it has different approach in handling validation on each platform. Cheers!

Comment: it's a default way for new project >>> windows form application (.net framwork)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this approach on KeyPress event:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var txt = (TextBox)sender;
        var newText = string.Concat(txt.Text, e.KeyChar);
        if (newText.ToArray().Count(t => t == '.') < 2 && newText.EndsWith("."))
            newText = newText.Remove(newText.Length - 1);

        if (newText == "-" || e.KeyChar == '\b')    
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            return;
        }

        var isvalid = Regex.IsMatch(newText, @"^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$");
        if (isvalid)
            e.Handled = false;
        else
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: wooow , thank you very much ..... very good solution ,,,, thank you again

Comment: Great! also you can check tab KeyChar for the form tab control.